# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function Is anybody know what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Here is the "custom-isotope-portfolio.js" file. Does anybody know what is wrong?

This is a wordpess site. Looks like there is a problem in theme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6aom.png)

```js
if (!$) $ = jQuery;

// Isotope for Portfolio

$(document).ready(function() {
 ('.vivaco-grid[id^="gridwrapper_"]').each( function() {
  var $div = $(this),
   token = $div.data('token'),
   settingObj = window['vsc_grid_' + token],
   $container = null,
   $optionSets = null,
   grid_gutter_width = settingObj.gutter_width;

  if (typeof settingObj === 'undefined') {
   $container = $(".grid_portfolio");
   $optionSets = $('#gridwrapper_portfolio #options .option-set');

  }else {
   $container = $(".grid_"+settingObj.id+"");
   $optionSets = $('#gridwrapper_'+settingObj.id+'  #options .option-set');

  }

  colWidth = function () {
   var w = $container.width(),
    columnNum = 1,
    columnWidth = 0;

   vals = settingObj.vals

   // apply default settings
   if (vals.grid_manager != 1) {
    if (w > 1440) {
     columnNum  = 4;

    } else if (w > 1365) {
     columnNum  = 3;

    } else if (w > 1279) {
     columnNum  = 3;

    } else if (w > 1023) {
     columnNum  = 3;

    } else if (w > 767) {
     columnNum  = 2;

    } else if (w > 479) {
     columnNum  = 2;

    }

   }else { // apply custom settings
    if (w > 1440) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_very_wide;

    } else if (w > 1365) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_wide;

    } else if (w > 1279) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_normal;

    } else if (w > 1023) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_small;

    } else if (w > 767) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_tablet;

    } else if (w > 479) {
     columnNum  = vals.grid_phone;

    }
   }


   columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);

   $container.find('.grid-item').each(function() {
    var $item = $(this),
     gwidth = 0;

    if (vals.grid_manager == 1) {
     gwidth = grid_gutter_width;

    }

    $item.css({'margin': Math.floor(gwidth/2)});

    if ($item.hasClass('item-wide')) {
     if (w < 480) {
      $item.css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth)-gwidth) * 0.7777777) + 'px'
      });

      $item.find('img').css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : '100%'
      });

     }else {
      $item.css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) * 0.7777777) + 'px'
      });

      $item.find('img').css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : '100%'
      });

     }
    }

    if ($item.hasClass('item-small')) {
     $item.css({
      'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
      'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth)-gwidth) * 0.7777777) + 'px'
     });

     $item.find('img').css({
      'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
      'height' : '100%'
     });

    }

    if ($item.hasClass('item-long')) {
     if (w < 480) {
      $item.css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth)-gwidth) * 0.7777777/2) + 'px'
      });

      $item.find('img').css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : '100%'
      });

     }else {
      $item.css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth)-gwidth) * 0.7777777) + 'px'
      });

      $item.find('img').css({
       'width' : ((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) + 'px',
       'height' : '100%'
      });

     }
    }

    if ($item.hasClass('item-high')) {
     $item.css({
      'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
      'height' : Math.round(((columnWidth*2)-gwidth) * 0.7777777) +'px'
     });

     $item.find('img').css({
      'width' : ((columnWidth)-gwidth) + 'px',
      'height' : '100%'
     });

    }
   });

   return columnWidth;
  }

  // Isotope Call
  gridIsotope = function () {
   $container.isotope({
    layoutMode : 'masonry',
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    animationEngine: 'jquery',
    resizable: false,
    masonry: { columnWidth: colWidth(), gutter: 35, isFitWidth: true }
   });
  };
  gridIsotope();
  $(window).smartresize(gridIsotope);


  // Portfolio Filtering
  $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');

   // don't proceed if already selected
   if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) return false;

   $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $this.addClass('selected');

   // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
   var options = {},
    key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
    value = $this.attr('data-option-value');

   // parse 'false' as false boolean
   value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
   options[ key ] = value;

   if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
    changeLayoutMode( $this, options ); // changes in layout modes need extra logic

   } else {
    $container.isotope( options ); // otherwise, apply new options

   }

   return false;
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You did not load Jquery.

Comment: This error means JQuery is missing.

Comment: Look at the screenshot. The error's stack trace *includes* calls from jquery.js

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you're right I didn't saw it, but I can name an empty script jquery.js if I want to.

Comment: Now I've added jquery to your snippet it produces a different error, `('.vivaco-grid[id^="gridwrapper_"]').each` is not a function, because there is no $ in front of that.

Comment: @NathanP. True enough, but unlikely. Plus, the error would be closer to `if(!$) $ = jQuery;` (name error on "jQuery") or `$(document).ready()` ($ not a function). My guesses here are either a scope error or a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have jquery loaded. try loading it through a cdn

Comment: Look at the screenshot. The error's stack trace *includes* calls from jquery.js

Comment: The snippet however does not include jquery.  Fixed.